# How to use react-native-share to share a photo on twitter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to use react-native-share to share a photo on twitter? currently when I try to share its sharing the image link instead of proper image how can I share image instead of its uri the image is in the cloud can anyone help me how to do this with my react native app?

```
 const HandleShareToTwitter = async () => {
        const options = {
            social: Share.Social.TWITTER,
            message: 'Deserunt ea sint magna dolor incididunt sit culpa id laborum cupidata.',
            url: image,
            email: 'codes.sg@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Eiusmod esse veniam esse.',
            recipient: '919988998899',
        };
        try {
            const res = await Share.shareSingle(options)
            console.log(res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

This is how I am generating a base64:

```
async function base64File(url) {
        const data = await fetch(url);
        const blob = await data.blob();
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                const base64data = reader.result;
                setImage(base64data)
                resolve(base64data);
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Share from react-native.

Share.share({ url: 'path_to_your_image or remote url'; social: Share.Social.TWITTER});